# Is Akavache Secure blob genuinely secure yet on Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, akavache

This [article](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/password-protected-encryption-provider-for-akavache) from a quarter of a decade ago says that Akavache is insecure on Xamarin even when using the Secure container.

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and I'm wondering if this is still the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still the case, you can see [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/blob/1cb732dec01f5c877f8a0e57cacdfe78673b101f/src/Akavache.Core/ProtectDataShim.cs), the article aslo says how you can implement your own encryption